# Here Map Api using Retrofit Get Call

Tags: here-api

i am using ReveseGeocode Rest Api using Retrofit and the Call give me nothing
and using Route api to get distance between two points
always Call response give "'Package-Name'@someNumbers"`

```
private static Retrofit reGeoHereRetrofit =null;
public static Retrofit getReGeoHereRetrofit(){
    if (reGeoHereRetrofit == null){
        reGeoHereRetrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://reverse.geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/6.2/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return reGeoHereRetrofit;
}
```

Interface.Class

```
public interface ReGeoHere {

@GET("reversegeocode.json")

public Call<ReGeoHereResponse> getReGeoAddress(@Query("prox") String LatLngD, @Query("mode") String 
Mode, @Query("maxresults") String MaxResults, @Query("gen") String Gen, @Query("apiKey") String 
MyApiKey, @Query("language") String Language);
}
```

and myclasses is getten using http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org for this json

```
{
"Response": {
    "View": [
        {
            "Result": [
                {
                    "Location": {
                        "Address": {
                            "Label": "S State St & W Madison St, Chicago, IL 60603, United States",
                            "Country": "USA",
                            "State": "IL",
                            "County": "Cook",
                            "City": "Chicago",
                            "District": "Loop",
                            "Street": "S State St & W Madison St"
                        }
                        
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of the examples:
curl 
-X GET 
-H 'Content-Type: *' 
--get 'https://reverse.geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/6.2/reversegeocode.json' 
--data-urlencode 'prox=41.8842,-87.6388,250' 
--data-urlencode 'mode=retrieveAddresses' 
--data-urlencode 'maxresults=1' 
--data-urlencode 'gen=9' 
--data-urlencode 'apiKey= '

https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/rest/geocoder/reverse-geocode
It does return the response. Could you please double check your implementation?